# Android - Cancel notifications from other apps

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications

I am trying to make a launcher which automatically cancels the notifications of some specific apps (whose package name is stored in variable `label`) registered in the SQLite database.

I have retrieved data from database in the NotificationListenerService onCreate() Method and cancelled the notification as soon as the are posted.

I have granted permissions to my NotificationListenerService to access notification content. But still when a new notification comes it doesn't gets logged.

My NotificationListenerService class looks like this:

```
public class AppsNotificationListenerService extends NotificationListenerService {

    AppsDbHelper appsDbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayList<AppItem> apps;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        appsDbHelper = new AppsDbHelper(this);
        db = appsDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        apps = new ArrayList<AppItem>();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(Constants.AppsEntry.TABLE_NAME,null, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    AppItem app = new AppItem();
                    app.label = cursor.getString(2);
                    app.name = cursor.getString(1);
                    int use = cursor.getInt(3);
                    if(use == 1){
                        app.isUseful=true;
                    }else{
                        app.isUseful=false;
                    }
                    if(!app.isUseful){
                        apps.add(app);
                    }

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            cursor.close();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        super.onNotificationPosted(sbn);
        Log.i("NotifListenerService", "Notification Posted");
        Log.i("NotifListenerService", sbn.getId()+"  "+sbn.getKey()+"  "+sbn.getPackageName());
        String packageName = sbn.getPackageName();
        for(AppItem app : apps){
            if(packageName.equals(app.label)){
                cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong?